# Pylint generates error message for cmap=plt.cm.Reds (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pylint

[image]

I am new to python and having issues with this random walk class. When I pass an argument to cmap I get a red underline for "plt".
Everything works fine with no issues except the problem is consistent in my problems section in the terminal.

```
problem/error
Module 'matplotlib.cm' has no 'Reds' member pylint(no-member) [12, 63]
```

Comment: Does the pylint warning go away if you use `cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("Reds")` instead of `cmap=plt.cm.Reds`?

Comment: My IDE always complains about colormaps but the code runs without problem. I understand that you get an error message during program execution. Is this consistently reproducible for [different colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (say `hot` or `plasma`) or is it restricted to Reds?

Comment: Please also always post code, data as text, not as images. There is a `{}` button that allows you to format code in your question.

Comment: What Python version are you using? what IDE and what version? what linter are you using? maybe also what Operating System? For me on Windows 10, Pycharm 2019  Python 3.6 , matplotlib 3.0.2 I don't see the error

Comment: @NEOchilidish Do you have the `from matplotlib import cm` module imported in your code? From the screenshot, it is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

use `cmap=plt.cm.Reds_r` instead of `cmap=plt.cm.Reds`

Comment: Kindly explain details to the answer you have provided in order to better understand it.

Comment: I was able to do using this but was unable to find relevant sources for better understanding if anyone finds please do share

Comment: Do you have the `from matplotlib import cm` module in your code?